# Hibernate findByExample on a Many to Many

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a question for some hibernate guru's

I have 3 tables `User`, `Car`, `CarList`

Carlist is a many to many

```
user --< carlist >-- car
```

I am trying to use the built in findByExample in order to query the carlist.

So far I have found out how to do it on one table like so:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(CarSearchList.class)
    .add(Example.create(instance))
    .createCriteria("car")
    .add(Example.create(instance.getCar()))
    .list();
```

But how can I do it on the car and user table? I tried this below but it fails:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(CarSearchList.class)
    .add(Example.create(instance))
    .createCriteria("car")
    .add(Example.create(instance.getCar()))
    .createCriteria("user")
    .add(Example.create(instance.getUser()))
    .list();
```

Comment: When you say "it fails" what happens exactly? Error? Results not what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out one way to do it:

```
    List results = session.createCriteria(CarSearchList.class)
    .add(Example.create(instance))
    .createAlias("car", "car")
    .createAlias("user", "user")
    .add( Restrictions.eqProperty("car.carId",    "user.userId"))
    .list();
```

From the manual 17.4. I skipped right passed it. Duh! Any ways I wonder what other ways there are to do this?